# how can i create custom laravel email template?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-blade

i need to create a custom email template for laravel mail service
i used below command for publish laravel email markdown.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

in resources/views folder i saw two folder named html and text
there is same blade file in each folder
what is difference between them?
how can i create a custom email template?
i tried to create two balde file with same name in each folder (html, text)
my question is what is difference between them?
and what i need to put to each of them?

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#configuring-the-view) didn't help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will publish the Markdown mail components to the `resources/views/vendor/mail` directory. The `mail` directory will contain an `html` and a `text` directory, each containing their respective representations of every available component. You are free to customize these components however you like.

See Official Documentation of (**Customizing The Components**) [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#customizing-the-components)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add /directory-of-markdown in Laravel Mailer. A template file is a simple blade file where you can basically do whatever you want to do. You can see something like following in your Mailable.

```
> public function build()
{
 return $this->from('example@example.com')
            ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

Just replace view with your custom template. You can also access data which is defined in your Mailable class. Please [see](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail)